# Suppose $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers such that $(a+b+c+1)(a^{-1}+b^{-1}+c^{-1}+1)=16$, then, $a+b+c=3$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

True or False:

Suppose $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers such that
$(a+b+c+1)(a^{-1}+b^{-1}+c^{-1}+1)=16$, then, $a+b+c=3$.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Please include your thoughts and any working you have done towards this question. People are more likely to help you if it doesn't look like you've just copied and pasted a homework question

Comment: Hint: Cauchy inequality

Comment: Looks like you want to impress your maths teacher!

Comment: LOL. ACTUALLY NOT MONK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$(a+b+c+1)(a^{-1}+b^{-1}+c^{-1}+1) \geq (1+1+1+1)^2 = 16$$
With equality iff $a=b=c=1$. Thus this statement is true.

Comment: THANK U SO MUCH FOR YOUR ANSWER ISSAC. REALLY Appreciate it